How do I get rid of this unnecessary gray whitespace in my website?
I have been trying to get rid of some big whitespace I do not need. This appeared after I have used display: grid to get rid of some positioning issues for my images.
Whitespace
Here's my ejs:

<%- include('./partials/header.ejs')%>

<main class = "gridMain"> 

    <div class = "movDescription item1"> 

        <h1 style = "color: red"> TCGCards.com </h1>
        <p> <b> Power to the People! </b> </p>
        <p>  
            
            <b>A marketplace for trading card collectors, and players. Here, we have a great and varied selection of 
            trading card goods from all over the world! You will never find any better deals then this!
            </b>
        </p>

     <div class = "movSearchBar"> 

        <div class = "fixhyperlink li a">
          
          <!-- /cards means that you want to see something specific. -->
          <!--/cards/ means you want to see whole section.  -->

        <div class = "movText">
         <a href = "/cards">  Browse Our Collection </a>
        </div>
          


        </div>

    </div>

    </div>

    <div class = "movIndexImages">
    
    <img src = "/images/pokemon.jpg" alt = "pokemon" class = "item2">

    <img src = "/images/yugioh.jpeg" alt = "yugioh" class = "item3" > 

    <img src = "/images/magic-the-gathering-2-558x331(resized).jpg"  alt = "MGT" class = "item4">

</div>

</main>

<%- include('./partials/footer.ejs')%>

Here's my css:

body{

    background-color: gray;
}

.cards{
    position: relative;
    left: 430px;
    top: 50px;
}

.movDetails{

    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
  
}

.movImage{

     position: relative;
     top: 50px;
}

.movIndexImages{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 50px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.hyperlink a{

    text-decoration: none;
    
}

.movNav{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 90px;
}

footer{

    background-color: rgb(217, 205, 205);
    color: white;
}

.gridMain{

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px;

    position: relative;
    left: 300px;
}

.item1{

    grid-row-start:1;
    grid-row-end: 20;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 20;

}

.item2{

  
    grid-row-start:1;
    grid-row-end: 20;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 20;

    position: relative;
    right: 300px;

    width: 530px;
}

.item3{

    grid-row-start:1;
    grid-row-end: 20;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 20;
   
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;

    position: relative;
    left: 300px;
    bottom: 530px;
}

.item4{

    grid-row-start:1;
    grid-row-end: 20;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 20;
   
    height: 300px;
    width:300px;

    position: relative;
    left: 300px;
    bottom: 460px;
}

.tag-remover a p{

    text-decoration: none;

}

.movTcg{

   position: relative;
   top: 40px;
   height: 110px;
}

.movDescription{
    position: relative;
    right: 300px;
    bottom: 100px;
}

.movSearchBar{

    position: relative;
    left: 350px;

}

.movText{

    position: relative; 
   left: 30px;
    top: 40px;


}

.movBrowserBar{
    position: relative;
    left: 300px;
}

.movHololive{
      position: relative;
      height: 300px;
      left: 200px;
      top: 80px;
}


.movFooter{

    position: relative;
    top: 100%;
    
    /* display:flex; */
    align-items:center; 
    justify-content: space-between;
}






.refFlex{

    /* display: flex; */
    justify-content: flex-end;
    gap: 30px;
    
/* Why is this refusing to be moved? */
    bottom: 50px;

}


/* Ul is whole box container containing ul. */
ul{

    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    gap: 20px;

}

/* Targets all li. Makes it seem like it forms a blue box, but 
 really all it is doing is making sure every li is 
 colored the set color. */
ul li{

    position: relative;
    bottom: 40px;
    right: 40px;
   
}

ul li a{
  
   
   
}

.items{
    display: flex;
    gap: 100px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: relative;
    left: 80px;
    
}



section .movItems{


   
}


section a img{

    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;
}

.item1 img{

    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
}





I tried to use this:
.tag-remover a p{
text-decoration: none;

}
But it did not do anything. I am unsure why this issue is occurring. I would have thought this would have easily fixed things since I am applying this to every p under my a tag.
Code snippet:


body {

  background-color: gray;
}

.cards {
  position: relative;
  left: 430px;
  top: 50px;
}

.movDetails {

  position: relative;
  top: 25px;

}

.movImage {

  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}

.movIndexImages {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.hyperlink a {

  text-decoration: none;

}

.movNav {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 90px;
}

footer {

  background-color: rgb(217, 205, 205);
  color: white;
}

.gridMain {

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px;

  position: relative;
  left: 300px;
}

.item1 {

  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 20;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 20;

}

.item2 {


  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 20;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 20;

  position: relative;
  right: 300px;

  width: 530px;
}

.item3 {

  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 20;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 20;

  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;

  position: relative;
  left: 300px;
  bottom: 530px;
}

.item4 {

  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 20;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 20;

  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;

  position: relative;
  left: 300px;
  bottom: 460px;
}

.tag-remover a p {

  text-decoration: none;

}

.movTcg {

  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  height: 110px;
}

.movDescription {
  position: relative;
  right: 300px;
  bottom: 100px;
}

.movSearchBar {

  position: relative;
  left: 350px;

}

.movText {

  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
  top: 40px;


}

.movBrowserBar {
  position: relative;
  left: 300px;
}

.movHololive {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  left: 200px;
  top: 80px;
}


.movFooter {

  position: relative;
  top: 100%;

  /* display:flex; */
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}






.refFlex {

  /* display: flex; */
  justify-content: flex-end;
  gap: 30px;

  /* Why is this refusing to be moved? */
  bottom: 50px;

}


/* Ul is whole box container containing ul. */
ul {

  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  gap: 20px;

}

/* Targets all li. Makes it seem like it forms a blue box, but 
 really all it is doing is making sure every li is 
 colored the set color. */
ul li {

  position: relative;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: 40px;

}

ul li a {}

.items {
  display: flex;
  gap: 100px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  left: 80px;

}



section .movItems {}


section a img {

  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
}

.item1 img {

  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
}

.tag-remover a p {

  text-decoration: none;

}
<%- include('./partials/header.ejs')%>

<main class="gridMain">

  <div class="movDescription item1">

    <h1 style="color: red"> TCGCards.com </h1>
    <p> <b> Power to the People! </b> </p>
    <p>

      <b>A marketplace for trading card collectors, and players. Here, we have a great and varied selection of 
            trading card goods from all over the world! You will never find any better deals then this!
            </b>
    </p>

    <div class="movSearchBar">

      <div class="fixhyperlink li a">

        <!-- /cards means that you want to see something specific. -->
        <!--/cards/ means you want to see whole section.  -->

        <div class="movText">
          <a href = "/cards">  Browse Our Collection </a>
        </div>



      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="movIndexImages">

    <img src = "https://i.sstatic.net/wQccJXY8.jpg" alt = "pokemon" class = "item2">

    <img src = "https://i.sstatic.net/GPFIcNtQ.jpg" alt = "yugioh" class = "item3" >

    <img src = "https://i.sstatic.net/n6MhE1PN.jpg"  alt = "MGT" class = "item4">

  </div>

</main>

<%- include('./partials/footer.ejs')%>




Positioning is a very poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out LearnLayout.com

I removed a lot of excess that was not a part of the actual presented page (question) for CSS or the top/bottom elements whatever those might be/were that I removed.
This is based on some assumptions of your desire to put a centered header block on the page with two columns of images below that.
I "super centered" some grids with
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;

Then you can just place the images in a simple 2X3 grid with the size you had set.


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16x;
}

body {
  background-color: #88888820;
  border: dashED #00FFFF 1px;
  width: fit-content;
}

.main-container,
.header-container,
.browse-container,
.image-container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.main-container {
  border: solid #0000FF 1px;
  width: fit-content;
}

.header-container {
  border: solid #FF0000 1px;
}

.header-text {
  color: #FF0000;
}

.image-container {
  border: solid #00ff00 1px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 300px, 1fr, 300px;
  gap: 1em;
}

.movIndexImages {
  z-index: -1;
}

.fixhyperlink a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.image-block {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.image-block.item2 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  grid-column: 1;
  width: 530px;
}

.image-block.item3 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.image-block.item4 {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  grid-column: 2;
}
<main class="gridMain main-container">
  <div class="movDescription header-container">
    <h1 class="header-text">TCGCards.com</h1>
    <p><b>Power to the People!</b></p>
    <p>
      <b>A marketplace for trading card collectors, and players. Here, we have a great and varied selection of trading card goods from all over the world! You will never find any better deals then this!</b>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="movSearchBar browse-container fixhyperlink">
    <div class="movText">
      <a href = "/cards">Browse Our Collection</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="movIndexImages image-container">
    <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/wQccJXY8.jpg" alt="pokemon" class="image-block item2">
    <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/GPFIcNtQ.jpg" alt="yugioh" class="image-block item3">
    <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/n6MhE1PN.jpg"  alt="MGT" class="image-block item4">
  </div>
</main>



